# Great variation in web statisics

Tags: statistics, analytics, tracker, awstats

I have a blog site, a WP 3.0 install.  I've dropped Google Analytics' tacker code into the footer (a recommended technique I believe).  I also have two different types of web statistic software available on the virtual server, through the hosting company.  However the web statistics vary greatly.  Why such variation?

Statitics -- 
http://pastebin.com/Nc10iGaA

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Google removes bot hits from it's traffic.  You might be seeing google bots in the other hit counts.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the software counts analytics differently. You should look at the documentation to figure out what qualifies a "visit," which may exclude/include crawlers, certain user agents, certain access patterns, etc.

Comment: Thanks, know of any good references for these types of stats?